# VueJS 2 - KeyUp doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify to generate input field with:

```
<v-text-field
  label="Search"
  v-model="search"
  @keyup.enter="search()"
  required
></v-text-field>
```

I want I can key up enter to search from this field:

```
search () {
  alert('test')
}
```

When I key up on enter key, this method doesn't executed...

Comment: You would want to use @keyup.enter.native="search()"

Comment: @JoelSmith Doesn't works too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use your `developer console` for debugging so you can see what error messages you are getting:

- *Windows*: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- *Mac*: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

The problem you are actually having here is that you have declared `search` as a data property *and* as a `method`, so you should see the following message:

> [Vue warn]: Method "search" has already been defined as a data property.

To fix this change you method name or your data property name:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    search() {
      alert('search')
    },
  },
  data: {
    searchTerm: ''
  }
})
```

And you should find it works fine.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/er9wsfcy/

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and everything was in order, turns out the Browser that i was using was the one with issues.

You can try viewing your console from a different browser eg **Chrome**.

Maybe this might help someone;