# Vuejs Keyup event not working

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Im trying to build an small Laravel/Vuejs chatroom and im having some issues when trying to take some data from an input field with a keyup event and pushing that into an array. Its just not working as well as not displaying any errors on the console.

This is my code:

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');



Vue.component('message', require('./components/message.vue'));



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: '',
        chat:{
            message:[]
        }
    },

    methods:{
        send(){
            if(this.message.length != 0) {
                this.chat.message.push(this.message);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

message.vue

```
<template>
    <li class="list-group-item"></li>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

chat.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

    <style>
        .list-group{
            margin-top:20px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="app">
        <ul class="list-group offset-4 col-4">
            <li class="list-group-item active">Chat Room</li>
            <message></message>
            <input v-model='message' @keyup.enter='send' type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="" placeholder="Type your message">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="{{'js/app.js'}}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone give me a clue on what is going on?

Thank you

Comment: You can check this out might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765108/2270348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no problems, and it works on jsFiddle:

```
<div id="app">
    {{ chat }}
    <ul class="list-group offset-4 col-4">
        <li class="list-group-item active">Chat Room</li>
        <message></message>
        <input v-model='message' @keyup.enter='send' type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message">
    </ul>
</div>


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: '',
        chat:{
            message:[]
        }
    },

    methods:{
        send(){
            alert();
            if(this.message.length != 0) {
                this.chat.message.push(this.message);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/OzanKurt/ewbz7m84/4/